# PDO Query not updating

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have set up my query correctly it comes back with NO errors at all but for someone reason does not update

```
$database->updateAdmin(1, $_POST['user']);

 public function updateAdmin($status, $uid) {
    $sql = 'UPDATE users SET admin = :status WHERE uid = :uid';
    $result = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute([
        ':status' => $status,
        ':uid' => $uid
    ]);
}

<select name="user">
      <option value="1">John</option>
     <option value="2">Sarah</option>
 </select>
```

admin field is ENUM ('0','1')

This is how it is all set up it just says it went ok but never updates, can anyone spot maybe why?

Comment: Are you checking for errors? Is your PDO object set to throw Exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

To make it come with errors you have to ask for them.
Have you set your PDO in exception mode?

However, there could be a hard-spotted trick.
You have to bind your 1 as a string, not as a number. Otherwise it won't update.
I am not quite familiar with automatic binding from array, but it is quite possible that PDO does some magic and binds your 1 as a number. So, I'd bind it manually, to be sure.

Comment: what magic would be needed? in `$database->updateAdmin(1, $_POST['user']);` it is already a number

Comment: That's not true. You can bind integers as well as strings.

Comment: All parameters passed in [`execute`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) are treated as `PDO::PARAM_STR`. If you want non-string bindings, you need to bind them explicitly.